# How can I get windows to let me install an unsigned app?

Tags: windows

I downloaded an `.appx` file from a service that my university uses, originally intended for Windows phone.

When I try to install the app (by double clicking the `.appx` file) I get the following:

> Ask the app developer for a new app package. This one isn't signed
>   with a trusted certificate (0x800B0100)

How can I get the app to install successfully?

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but based on the discussion at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/489#issuecomment-496170540, it looks like it may not be possible.

Comment: I don't know how new it is, but as of 2024 you may be able to use the `-AllowUnsigned` flag to install unsigned Appxpackages (for developer scenarios): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-allowunsigned

Answer (score 0):

How to install an unsigned appx packages on Windows 10:

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on Update & security.
3. Click on For developers.
4. Under “Use developer features”, enable Developer mode. Enable Developer mode on 5. 5. Windows 10.
5. Click Yes.
6. Restart your computer to complete the task.

From: [PureInfoTech](https://pureinfotech.com/install-unsigned-windows-10-apps-powershell/)